# UIImage View shifting in Interface Builder

Tags: cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I am using interface builder to create my create my .nib file.  THe first thing I did was to add an UIImage view to cover the screen with a background image that serves as part of the interface graphic.  Everything was working fine, now the image is shifted up slightly in the simulator.  THe Status, Top, and Bottom bar are all "Unspecified".  Has anyone encountered this issue and found a way to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the size of your view in the nib the same size as it will be in the simulator? If it's smaller, your autoresizing masks may be centering it vertically. Verify that it's the correct size, and then verify the autoresizing masks in IB are set the way you want them to be.